# Android: Timer in BackgroundService for Location

Tags: android, location

I have an app that consists of a few Activities. I want the when my app starts up, the I start listening for updates from the LocationManager, and after a few minutes, I want to time out and stop listening for updates. I've done this in other apps, but where I only have one Activity.

What I have now is a BackgroundService that starts listening for LocationUpdates; if it gets a good enough location quickly, it stops listening for updates. But sometimes it doesn't get a good location quickly, and I want it to time out, so I have a Timer that stops listening for updates after a bit. This works fine when I start the App and stay in the first Activity.

The problem is when I start the app, then start using the app and other Activities start, the Timer never goes off, so LocationManager is always on, until the app quits.

Thoughts? Is there a better way to listen to location updates so any Activity in the app can get the location, and ensure that it times out to stop listening for updates?

**Update:** 
It turns out the BackgroundService gets destroyed when I switch Activities, and I cancel the timer in onDestroy(). Thanks for the response-- that was enough to confirm that the general approach was reasonable and I probably had a silly mistake somewhere (true).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the Timer in the background service ? That will solve the issue.

Comment: The Timer is in the BackgroundService. If I start the app and stay on the first Activity, the Timer goes off as desired. If I go to a different Activity, the Timer doesn't go off.

Comment: Then you must be shutting down the service ? Are you catching Exceptions without logging them ? If none of this helps, post some code so we can see the details of your implementation.